# Positioning image on the page

Tags: html, css

I have an image in ASP.NET, I hope I can explain this very clearly so you can give very clear answers.

My master form has the following setup:

```
.page
{
    width: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid #496077;
    height: auto;
}

.header
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #4b6c9e;
    width: 100%;
}

.header h1
{
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    border: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.main
{
    padding: 0px 12px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
}

.leftCol
{
    padding: 6px 0px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.footer
{
    color: #4e5766;
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

I have a "contact us" page with variable information about each entry for a person on the left hand margin side of the page (name, address, contact info, etc.). I want to position an image that is just a few pixels past the most far right information given for a certain person, and I want the heightxwidth of the picture to vary based on the height of the text (if the user was to enter more lines for information for each contact person, etc.)

How can I get an image with this positioning? So far I've been able to get an image on the far right side of the screen, but this is not good, as I would like to have 2 columns of contact information for more space on the form.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
<h1>Contact Information<b><img align="left" alt="pic" class="bold" 
        src="profilepic.jpg" 
        style="width: 150px; height: 150px; float: right;" vspace="0" /></b></h1>
<b><h2>adsf</h2>
adsf</b> <br />
asdf<br />
asdf</br>
asdf <br />
asdf <br />
asdf
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For questions such as this, it would help clarify what you want if you can abstract your question: "Given X, I want Y to be in Z, and I have tried N". Barring that, give us a JSFiddle containing an example of what you want to achieve. Performing these steps you're also likely to find the solution yourself.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/39q4b2oh/?

Answer (score 0):

have you ever considered using a table? You can style the rows width, text alignment, vertical alignment, and all other styles yadda yadda through using classes; or however you choose. But that will set you up with columns and rows for each person....

```
<table class="table">
      <tr class="tableRow">
            <td class="tableDataLeft">
             Some Persons info Number 1
             </td>
            <td class="tableDataMiddle">
             Person Number 1's second column of info
             </td>
            <td class="tableDataRight">
             Person number 1's image...<img src/>
            </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
            <tdclass="tableDataLeft">
             Some Persons info Number 2
             </tdclass="tableDataLeft">
            <td class="tableDataMiddle">
             Person Number 2's second column of info
             </td>
            <td class="tableDataRight">
             Person number 2's image...<img src/>
            </td>          
      </tr>
</table>
```